# Javascript Variable Scope - Values Not Assigning

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a calendar application and I'm having trouble setting values to my globally declared variables and then accessing those values in another function.

Here is some of the code. If you need more please comment and I can paste it all

```
var eventhold = [];
var eyears = [];
var emonth = [];
var eday = [];
var events;

var loadData = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getevents.php"
  }).done(function(data) {

    events = JSON.parse(data); //returning json object

    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      eventhold[i] = events[i].eDate; //returns 2015-06-15 for each object

      eyears[i] = eventhold[i].substring(0, 4); //trims to 2015
      emonth[i] = eventhold[i].substring(5, 7); //trims to 06
      emonth[i] = parseInt(emonth[i]); //change to int
      emonth[i] --; //decrement to 0 base
      eday[i] = eventhold[i].substring(8, 10); //trims to 08
      eday[i] = parseInt(eday[i]); //change to int
    }

  });
}

function test() {
  firstDay = new Date(oDate.cyear, oDate.cmonth, 1); //return date for the "current year/ current month"
  numDay = firstDay.getDay(); // find the starting day for calendar offset

  console.log(eyears.length);
  // var times = eyears.length;
  // console.log(times);

  for (i = 0; i < eyear.length; i++) {
    console.log("first for");
    if (oDate.cyear == eyears[i] && oDate.cmonth == emonth[i]) //none of these values are registering. Again this all works in the console.
    {
      console.log("inside if");
      $("#day" + eday[i + numDay]).append(events[i].eName + "<br>" + events[i].eTime); //adding numDay to match the calendar "offset"
    }
  }
}
```

When I paste this for loop in the console it works perfectly and everything outputs fine. But I can't get any of the values into this function. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if anything is unclear and I can paste more code I'm just hoping not to overwhelm.

Comment: The intention of not overwhelming is good. However it would be very helpful if you could be more specific about what's not working and where. Also you could probably simplify your code, please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And also it looks like you have a typo or 2... (`eyear.length` looks wrong). You should look at your console for errors.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. Are you sure your real code is waiting for all the AJAX calls to finish before it tries to use the variables? You haven't shown the code that calls `loadData` and `test`.

Comment: Why is `events` a global variable instead of local to the callback function?